# How to handle MFA in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have created DAG file that lists the S3 files. This Dag file is working fine when there is no multi-factor authentication(MFA) enabled. After that, I have enabled the AWS account MFA then the DAG file is showing the "Access denied" exception. Can anyone know how to handle multi-factor authentication in Airflow while listing S3 files

Answer (score 0):

MFA tokens on AWS are only valid for 1 hour (or *maybe* 6 hours at max) so using MFA tokens for any kind of programatic access is never really going to work without a lot of manual intervention (i.e. re-populating the "token" field in the S3 connection string in this context.)

So in short: you can't really handle this in Airflow or any other long running service.